# Is it safe to pull the power plug off of the monitors?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, power-supply, power

I have four monitors plugged in through Amazon Smart plug so that I can turn off all the monitors with ease while keeping the Desktop running.

But one of the monitors recently failed. Is it safe to turn off power to the monitors abruptly (like I do with Amazon smart plug)?

Or, do I need to go to the Monitor menu, click on Turn off first? Is it safe to disconnect power abruptly to the monitors? Would it cause damage to the monitor?

Comment: It is better in my view to use the power switch to turn off a device and the unplug after it is turned off.

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? Define what "unsafe" in the context of these monitors would be exactly? You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited. My question is about avoiding damage to the monitors

Answer (score 1):

Low quality switches e.g. on [AC power bars](https://www.google.se/search?q=ac%20power%20bar) may cause glitches that are bad for any electronics.

Generally you are more safe with the power on/off button on the device itself.

*Note: A "glitch" is an electrical "jolt".*

---

*The above is based on personal experimenting with pulling off and reattaching power lines off/onto "pins" (AMP MOD IV), comparing with a low quality switch and a good switch - while sampling that with a Tek 4000-series oscilloscope.*

*Why do this? I simply needed to know, to be able to tell. And NO, that was not AC voltages (230V) - but I'd expect to see the same there.*

*Switches are more complex than you might think, if you would make your own.*